# XPath returns two identical results when only one is visible in HTML

Tags: html, xpath

Why does an XPath return two identical results when only one is visible in the HTML? For example, on the following URL:

https://www.concertgebouw.nl/en/concerts/gavrylyuk-and-concertgebouw-orchestra-schumann-s-piano-concerto/11-02-2018/special=Royal+Concertgebouw+Orchestra

I'm trying the following XPath:

```
.//div[@class="vtab-content-part"]/h3[contains(text(),"Musicians")]/parent::div[1]/node()
```

And the response is:

```
['\n        ', '<h3>Musicians</h3>', '\n        \n            \n                        
\n            \n            ', '<p>Koninklijk Concertgebouworkest 
</p>', '\n        \n            \n                        \n                            
\n                                                            \n                                                                                                                                        
\n                                                                        
\n            ', '<p>Stanislav Kochanovsky  - conductor </p>', '\n        
\n            \n                        \n                            
\n                                                            \n                        
\n                                                                        
\n            ', '<p>Alexander Gavrylyuk  - piano </p>', '\n            
', '\n        ', '<h3>Musicians</h3>', '\n        \n            \n                        
\n            \n            ', '<p>Koninklijk Concertgebouworkest 
</p>', '\n        \n            \n                        \n                        

\n                                                            \n                                                                                                                                        
\n                                                                        
\n            ', '<p>Stanislav Kochanovsky  - conductor </p>', '\n        
\n            \n                        \n                            
\n                                                            
\n                        \n                                                                        
\n            ', '<p>Alexander Gavrylyuk  - piano </p>', '\n            
']
```

The only matching HTML I see on the page is:

```
<div class="vtab-content-part">
    <h3 class=>Musicians</h3>
        <p class>Koninklijk Concertgebouworkest </p>
      <p class>Stanislav Kochanovsky  - conductor </p>
        <p class>Alexander Gavrylyuk  - piano </p>
</div>
```

Comment: What tool are you using to get those duplicates?

Comment: Originally I was working in Scrapy (Python 3), then just tried using requests, then I decided to eliminate any possible complications by using the XPath tool in Chrome. They all return the same thing.

Comment: I think that is because when you look at the source the elements like `<h3>Musicians</h3>` are there twice.

Comment: In fact, `<div class="vtab-content-part">` is at line 435 and line 727 of the source.

Comment: OK I see this. Thank you. The way to isolate it once is using `.//main[@class="content content--cdp"]//h3[contains(text(),"Musicians")]/parent::div[1]/node()`. What is the reason for writing all this HTML a second time and hiding it?